# What's the red, white and blue (with stars) banner that Trump was using on the stage in his election campaign?

Tags: united-states, flag, symbols

During election campaign rallys, Trump was always on stages decorated with a red-white-blue-white-red banner with white stars on the blue part. I of course know that's the US colors and the stars are a reference to the national flag - but, is there a name for this flag / banner? I also saw a round version with the blue in the middle (IIRC) and then white and red circles around that.

Is that just a "let's throw some patriotic colors together and make it look nice"? Or does it have any deeper meaning?

[image: Trump election campaign ralley]

[Source](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2020/10/31/biden-and-trump-in-battleground-blitz-us-election-live-news)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

It's standard American Flag Bunting, which is the standard way to render the American Flag in a linear, banner form.

You've most likely seen it curled into a half-circle ring for decoration, particularly on the 4th of July, but also at other political events. Here's a picture from around the time of [President Obama's inauguration](https://www.nytimes.com/2009/01/18/us/politics/18obama.html):

[image]

But the actual form is a long banner:

[image]

It doesn't have any other meaning beyond being Patriotic.

As *chrylis* points out, one of the reasons Bunting is used so often is that it's a more respectful way to use the American flag for decorative purposes. The [US Flag code](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/4/8) discourages draping the flag or using it for decorative purposes. Bunting is a way to be patriotic without disrespecting the actual flag.

Comment: A better resource for Flag Code is: https://www.military.com/flag-day/us-flag-code.html I'm pretty sure this is the actual Flag Code. Even if it isn't, it references the actual laws.

Comment: Comments deleted. This is not a place to debate the US flag code.

Comment: See also [subsection (d) there](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/4/8): "Bunting of blue, white, and red, always arranged with the blue above, the white in the middle, and the red below, should be used for covering a speaker’s desk, draping the front of the platform, and for decoration in general." Seemingly the bunting Trump's and Obama's respective staffs used was not up to code. And thus I'm not sure this answer is correct that the bunting pictured is "standard": if it is standard, that's unfortunate.